# Inconsistent damper control and ventilation control settings

Tags: hvac

While changing my dual-zone HVAC system's filters I noticed a lack of consistency in damper control and ventilation control settings. There are two of each type of control.

The first damper control has the red knob all the way to the right and the second damper control has it all the way to the left.

The first ventilation control is set to On (*Optimized ventilation*) and the second to Off (*Remote Only*)

I believe the first damper control and ventilation control correspond to the first floor, and the second damper control and ventilation control to the second.

I am concerned this could lead to an imbalance in workload distribution and attendant negative consequences.

Is this necessarily a problem?

Temperatures are currently in the high 90s where I live. The first level thermostat is set to 75 and the second level thermostat to 76.

[image: First damper control]
[image: First ventilation control]
[image: Second damper control]
[image: Second ventilation control]

Comment: Would you clarify which damper and ventilation control go to which floor?

Comment: @DanielGriscom, I've now clarified this in the question (first set to first floor, second to second).